# How VOIP + PushKit re-launch application from background/killed from background?

Tags: ios, voip, ios10, pushkit

I have registered app for background modes: Voice over IP, Background fetch and Remote Notifications.

When i receive VOIP push then my callkit initiate the call successfully, but once i accept the call then it won't re-launch the app from background.

Best example is Skype, which relaunch the application from background and start skype call.

I tried to provide background support and end background task in push token delegate but it didn't work.

Is there any documentation available for this?

Comment: Its resolved now, provided some delay in end call and initiate app functionality on answering call function.

Comment: can you give some more details? I'm using PushKit too, but it app wakes up only once.